# try with resource, will resource clean if thrown exception is not caught?

Tags: java, java-8

What happens when a try-with-resource throws an exception which is caught outside? Will a cleanup still be performed?

Sample:

```
public void myClass() throws customException {
  try (Connection conn = myUtil.obtainConnection()) {
     doSomeStuff(conn);
     if (someCheck)
       throw new customException(somePara);

     doSomeMoreStuff(conn);
     conn.commit();

  } catch (SQLException e) {
     log.error(e);
  }
}
```

The part I'm concerned with is when the customException is thrown. I do not catch this exception with the catch of my try-with-resource. Hence I wonder if the connection cleanup will be performed in this scenario.

Or do I need to catch and rethrow the connection, like this:

```
public void myClass() throws customException {
  try (Connection conn = myUtil.obtainConnection()) {
     doSomeStuff(conn);
     if (someCheck)
       throw new customException(somePara);

     doSomeMoreStuff(conn);
     conn.commit();

  } catch (SQLException e) {
     log.error(e);
  } catch (customException e) {
     throw new customException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `close()` method of the resource will be called, no matter if you catch the exception or not. It is not necessary to catch and re-throw the exception.

Comment: on your second example, isn't going to loop between `catch` and `throw new` ? plus when you try with resources you don't have to close the stream by hand `close()` will be called automatically

Comment: @PhillAlexakis No this will not cause an infinite loop between the catch and throw new, because the throw is not inside the try-block.

Comment: @Jesper oh alright

Comment: Actually, you don't need to retro the exception, you don't need to catch it at all. There's no need for either `catch` nor `finally` block in a`try-with-resources`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the cleanup will happen... if the `close()` method correctly handles the cleanup:

#### Example of execution

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (AutoCloseable c = () -> System.out.println("close() called")) {
      throw new Exception("Usual failure");
    }
  }
}
```

(shortened by Holger in the comments)

Output on stdout:

```
close() called
```

Output on stderr:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Usual failure
    at Main.main(Main.java:4)
```

#### Example of execution with an exception thrown in the `close()` method

(suggested by Holger in the comments)

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (AutoCloseable c = () -> { throw new Exception("Failure in the close method"); }) {
      throw new Exception("Usual failure");
    }
  }
}
```

No output on stdout.

Output on stderr:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Usual failure
    at Main.main(Main.java:4)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: Failure in the close method
        at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:3)
        at Main.main(Main.java:3)
```

Answer (score 5):

A documentation has an answer to your exact question

> Note: A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed.
>
> If an exception is thrown from the try block and one or more exceptions are thrown from the try-with-resources statement, then those exceptions thrown from the try-with-resources statement are suppressed, and the exception thrown by the block is the one that is thrown by the writeToFileZipFileContents method. You can retrieve these suppressed exceptions by calling the Throwable.getSuppressed method from the exception thrown by the try block.

Please have a look https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Yes and no. I have checked the docs but did not understand the statement really. Reason was some misunderstand of the try with resource concept which was clarified in another answer. Now it indeed makes sense

Comment: Why did anyone downvote this answer? This answer is as correct as my own!